# WP-Admin shows (1) update but there is no update for plugin, theme or Wordpress

Tags: wp-admin, updates, dashboard

I am having a strange issue where in my wp-admin it says there is an update required. However I checked the Themes, Plugins and even reinstalled the latest version of Wordpress and it is still showing me the update.

I have also deleted my cache plugin and done all sorts of other tasks to try to fix it but have no luck.

Would anyone have any idea of what could be causing this and/or how I can fix this? It is very annoying. Thank you for any help.

Here are 2 pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Multisite installation? If so, you need to go to the Network Admin pages to see the plugin or theme updates.

Comment: Hey @PatJ, no this is a single site. Would you have any idea what to do for a single site in this situation?

Comment: I'm afraid not. All I'd try is clicking the **Check Again** button and see if that resets whatever is causing your issue.

Comment: This isn't an answer but I found by accident that if I enable and then disable "troubleshooting mode" with the Health Check and Troubleshooting plugin that the "1" goes away. Maybe the Health Check and Troubleshooting plugin in causes the phantom 1 but either way it does clear it up.
Dennis

Comment: There seem to be various reasons- sometimes a plugin comming together with a theme causes that. I had the same issue with enfold theme and the included WP Layer Slider

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this on a few of the sites we manage, and the fix for us was updating translations from the WP Updates page. After scrolling all the way to the bottom and clicking "Update Translations," the (1) in the update icon in the admin bar went away. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It has been driving me crazy for months.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped. 

Comment: Still great solution, never would have thought to look there:)

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue in different WordPress installs, I manage more than 40 sites with WordPress, and this issue is very common, I've seen it in sites with different plugin combinations, with different themes, I've notice that when I reinstall WordPress it shows OK, but before it seems that there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I first reinstalled WP. Then I went into the Theme Support Center and enabled Safe Mode. This temporarily deactivates all plugins. Next, I disabled Safe Mode, and presto, no more pending updates! :)

If you're not running the same theme as me, you might try disabling all plugins and then enabling them again to see if that works for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Got the same issue on a multisite.
Deleting all rows with metakey like _site_transient_% from wp_sitemeta does the trick for me.